# How to make Pipeline job to wait for all triggered parallel jobs?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I've Groovy script as part of the Pipeline job in Jenkins as below:

```
node {
    stage('Testing') {
        build job: 'Test', parameters: [string(name: 'Name', value: 'Foo1')], quietPeriod: 2, wait: false
        build job: 'Test', parameters: [string(name: 'Name', value: 'Bar1')], quietPeriod: 2, wait: false
        build job: 'Test', parameters: [string(name: 'Name', value: 'Baz1')], quietPeriod: 2, wait: false
        build job: 'Test', parameters: [string(name: 'Name', value: 'Foo2')], quietPeriod: 2, wait: false
        build job: 'Test', parameters: [string(name: 'Name', value: 'Bar2')], quietPeriod: 2, wait: false
        build job: 'Test', parameters: [string(name: 'Name', value: 'Baz2')], quietPeriod: 2, wait: false
    }
}
```

which executes multiple other freestyle jobs in parallel, because of `wait` flag being set to `false`. However I'd like for the caller job to finish when all jobs are finished. Currently the Pipeline job triggers all the jobs and finishes it-self after few seconds which is not what I want, because I cannot track the total time and I don't have ability to cancel all triggered jobs at one go.

How do I correct above script for Pipeline job to finish when all jobs in parallel are completed?

I've tried to wrap build jobs in `waitUntil {}` block, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You should use pipeline *parallel* expression, which will wait for all spawned jobs / subtasks to complete:

```
stage('testing') {
    def branches = [:]

    for(i = 0; i < params.size(); i += 1) {
        def param = params[i]

        branches["Test${i}"] = {
            build job: 'Test', parameters: [string(name: 'Name', value: param)], quietPeriod: 2
        }
    }
    parallel branches
}
```

You can find some more examples in pipeline docs at [jenkins.io](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/examples/)

Answer (score 13):

Just run into the same problem, and find a working solution. Just use foreach.

```
stage('testing') {
    def jobs = [:]

    [1,2,3,4,5].each{
        i -> jobs["Test${i}"] = {
            build job: 'Test', 
            parameters: [string(name: 'theparam', value: "${i}")],
            quietPeriod: 2
        }
    }
    parallel jobs
}
```

Comment: That's super helpful. Thanks. I expanded upon it a bit over on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53765922/329496

Answer (score 8):

This works for me. Triggers 3 jobs. Wait for them to finish.
Pay attention to the extra "->" to specify groovy closure.
I have one -> on the each loop, and one on the parallel line.
It means that the value will be evaluated when running the parallel section.

```
def jobsString = "job1,job2,job3"
ArrayList jobsList = jobsString.split('\\,')

def parallelJobs2Run = [:]
jobsList.each { job ->
    echo "Going to parallel for job ${job}"
    parallelJobs2Run["${job}"] = { ->
        echo "Calling job ${job}"
        jobResults=build job: "${pathJenkinsFolder}${job}",
        parameters: [
            string(name: 'param1', value: "${value1}"),
            string(name: 'param2', value: "${value2}")
        ],
        propagate: true,
        wait: true

        // List of values: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46262862/how-to-i-get-the-url-of-build-triggered-with-build-step-on-jenkins
        buildNumber = ${jobResults.number}
        echo "${job} Build number |${buildNumber}| result: |${jobResults.result}|"
        echo "See details on: |${jobResults.absoluteUrl}|"
    }
};
parallel parallelJobs2Run
```

Answer (score 7):

However [@agg3l's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40148397) is not working with multiple jobs.

```
Map jobResults = [:]

Boolean failedJobs = false
def buildJobWithParams(def jobs_list, Map results) {
  def branches = [:]    
  for(job in jobs_list)
  {
    print job
    branches["Test-${job}"] = {
       def jobBuild = build job: job, propagate: false
       def jobResult = jobBuild.getResult()
       echo "Build of '${job}' returned result: ${jobResult}"
       results[job] = jobResult
    }
  }    
  return branches
}

stage('Run integration tests') {
      steps {
            def job_branch = buildJobWithParams(item_list, jobResults)
            print job_branch
            parallel job_branch
          }
}
```

The `item_list` has more than 1 job, however it will execute only last job multiple times.

Comment: Ever find a fix for this? I'm seeing same behavior @kenorb

Comment: It seems to me that the *job* variable is created outside the _for_ closure, so when the parallel is executed it will always take the last value. Try creating a new var inside the for like:

`
    for(job in jobs_list)
      {
        def myJob = job
        print myJob
        branches["Test-${myJob}"] = {
           def jobBuild = build myJob: myJob, propagate: false
           def jobResult = jobBuild.getResult()
           echo "Build of '${myJob}' returned result: ${jobResult}"
           results[myJob] = jobResult
        }
      }
`

Comment: Hmm, I've used same one parametrized job (with workflow dependent on parameters supplied)… Think it can be called job proxy/multiplexer.
Hadn't tried to spawn _different Jenkins jobs_ in parallel, honestly

Answer (score 3):

Another approach that basically does the same thing is wrapping your jobs in a separate stage and then wrapping all sub-stages in `parallel{}`, like so:

```
stage('Trigger all dependent jobs') {
    parallel {
        stage('Trigger task 1') {
            steps {
                build job: "task-1"
            }
        }
        stage('Trigger task 2') {
            steps {
                build job: "task-2"
            }
        }
        stage('Trigger task 3') {
            steps {
                build job: "task-3"
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

This approach allows you to do whatever you want on each parallel stage - the tasks above may very well be entirely different (from one another) Jenkins jobs.

Also, the above approach (to my knowledge) represents the *declarative* pipeline syntax.