# How to I get the url of build triggered with build step on Jenkins?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

While using Groovy based pipelines in Jenkins you can trigger child jobs using the the [build stage](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/).

Still the documentation above states nothing regarding what kind of return object you would get and what attributes it has.

The only thing I found so far is that I can use `build.getResult()` to obtain the result of the triggered job.

Still, I do want to obtain the URL of this job.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the documentation for the `build` step in `/pipeline-syntax` (`waitFormCompletion` argument, the original has better formatting):

> You may ask that this Pipeline build wait for completion of the downstream build. In that case the return value of the step is an object on which you can obtain the following read-only properties: so you can inspect its .result and so on.
>
> - number
>     build number (integer)
> - result
>     typically SUCCESS, UNSTABLE, or FAILURE (may be null for an ongoing build)
> - currentResult
>     typically SUCCESS, UNSTABLE, or FAILURE. Will never be null.
> - resultIsBetterOrEqualTo(String)
>     Compares the current build result to the provided result string (SUCCESS, UNSTABLE, or FAILURE) and returns true if the current build result is better than or equal to the provided result.
> - resultIsWorseOrEqualTo(String)
>     Compares the current build result to the provided result string (SUCCESS, UNSTABLE, or FAILURE) and returns true if the current build result is worse than or equal to the provided result.
> - displayName
>     normally #123 but sometimes set to, e.g., an SCM commit identifier
> - description
>     additional information about the build
> - id
>     normally number as a string
> - timeInMillis
>     time since the epoch when the build was scheduled
> - startTimeInMillis
>     time since the epoch when the build started running
> - duration
>     duration of the build in milliseconds
> - durationString
>     a human-readable representation of the build duration
> - previousBuild
>     another similar object, or null
> - nextBuild
>     similarly
> - absoluteUrl
>     URL of build index page
> - buildVariables
>     for a non-Pipeline downstream build, offers access to a map of defined build variables; for a Pipeline downstream build, any variables set globally on env
> - changeSets
>     a list of changesets coming from distinct SCM checkouts; each has a kind and is a list of commits; each commit has a commitId, timestamp, msg, author, and affectedFiles each of which has an editType and path; the value will not generally be Serializable so you may only access it inside a method marked @NonCPS
> - rawBuild
>     a hudson.model.Run with further APIs, only for trusted libraries or administrator-approved scripts outside the sandbox; the value will not be Serializable so you may only access it inside a method marked @NonCPS
>
> If you do not wait, this step succeeds so long as the downstream build can be added to the queue (it will not even have been started). In that case there is currently no return value.

The job URL doesn't exist (it's a build, after all), but `absoluteUrl` gives you the build URL.

`rawBuild` should let you access e.g. `rawbuild.parent.url` (untested), but it's generally unsafe and discouraged to leave the sandbox.

Comment: Thank you! Testing it now, in fact I found myself that the returned object seems to be a WorkflowRun instance. Still the official documentation from https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/ fails to provide information about the returned object and even worse is almost impossible to read the parameters. You can find "description" param listed 8 times and you have no idea to what it does apply. The HTML formatting of the docs sucks, BIG TIME.

Comment: @sorin No, just pretends to be. You're getting a RunWrapper: https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-support-plugin/blob/01f9538af15cf9cf76dfb928e40595d7df82be76/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/build/RunWrapper.java

Comment: @sorin Patches welcome: https://github.com/jenkins-infra/pipeline-steps-doc-generator –– While it's not great but it's not meant as the primary reference either. It can never show exactly what's available on your instance, after all.

Comment: @DanielBeck No such property: absoluteUrl for class: groovy.lang.Binding 
Got the error while running a pipeline job. Please let me know if any other way is available to get the BUILD_URL for the jobs triggered inside a pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer is fine only for passed Jobs. Failing ones return null from build step. There is a corresponding Bug https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-48475. It's set as RESOLVED because such behavior is expected, but IMO that's not correct as there is not alternative to get info from failed jobs

Answer (score 2):

set `propagate` to `false` - build step will pass and it will return the output with result field

Here is the code:

```
def success = "SUCCESS"
def build_run
build_run = build job: 'pass', propagate: false
println build_run.result
if (build_run.result == success)
    println('job1 passed')
else
    println('job1 failed')
build_run = build job: 'fail', propagate: false
println build_run.result
if (build_run.result == success)
    println('job2 passed')
else
    println('job2 failed')
```