# Jenkins Email notification for multiple builds

Tags: jenkins

I need suggestion for Jenkins project (multi-conf or pipeline) and plugins that will fit my work.

I have 10 "flavors" of the product, so I must build 10 times every time I commit to the repository (all in the same workspace, run in sequentially). Today I have 10 jobs (freestyle) and a "master" job that trigger the rest. I tried to add Email notification (using Email Extension Plugin) but I want only one Email report for all the builds, not 10 Emails.

I understand that I should change to one multi-configuration project or one pipeline project that will handle all the builds, so it will be easier to trigger only one Email, but what is the best practice to get only one Email report on multiple builds?

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact scenario which we can achieve using Pipeline job(Jenkinsfile) from which you can trigger all those freeStyle build-jobs in parallel and collect the build-url and build-status of those and store in some file, then use the email plugin in the post-build task to send the status of your complete flow.

You can use the following link to find how to access build variable post calling that inside your pipeline.
[How to I get the url of build triggered with build step on Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46262862/how-to-i-get-the-url-of-build-triggered-with-build-step-on-jenkins)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am trying to use pipeline job for that, but my groovy script just put all the relevant jobs in schedule and reach to the post section without waiting for the jobs to end. So I can't collect the results in the post section. 
This is the groovy code that build the other jobs, maybe it's wrong: `for (def jobV : view.getAllItems().fullDisplayName) {build job: jobV, wait: false}`

Comment: the `view` is configure before the loop in this line `def view = Hudson.instance.getView('eCos')` eCos is the name of the relevant view group.

Comment: while calling build job why don't you wait for the execution completion? That can be achieved with - jenkins_build_job = build(job: job_name, parameters: pipeline_params, propagate: false, wait: true)