# How to divide one jenkins job between multiple slaves

Tags: testing, jenkins, automated-tests

I have one python script that run multiple tests. the tests to be executed can be passed to it through the command line. I want that jenkins will divide the tests between its slaves. is anyone know how can i do that?

Is it possible to configure a job to repeat itself with other parameter, maybe?

Comment: It is possible for sure, but are you using a Pipeline job or a Freestype job?

Comment: For now i am using freestyle job, but if it will be needed i will create no matter what kind of job it will require..

Comment: I did something similar for a customer not long ago and even included in some of my lectures (see: https://www.tikalk.com/posts/2018/01/30/jenkins-pipeline-lecture-slide/) and if you're in Israel, we can even talk about it - contact me yorammi@tikalk.com

Comment: Seems parallel pipeline job can be a solution you're looking for, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40143500/

Comment: seems good. But can it connect all the results files into one big report?