# Jenkins run few jobs and get their result

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I run job like this:

```
  def job = build job: job_name,  parameters:
  [
    string(name: 'Param1', value: Value1),
    string(name: 'Param2', value: Value2),
    string(name: 'Param3', value: Value3),
  ], wait: false
  
  return job
```

I use `wait: false` because I need to run few in same time and then waiting for all of them finished. But in this case job is null because I use `wait: false`.

Maybe do you know other way to run multiply jobs in same time and get their objects ?

---

Other way that I try:

```
def buildsNumberStart = GetLastDockerBuildNumber(DockerBuildJobName)
def finishedJobs = overrideBranches.collect { item -> RunJobBuild(item.Tag, author, GetImageNameFromRepository(item.DockerRepository), item.Name, item.Branch, item.Repository, DockerBuildJobName)}
sleep(30)
def buildNumberFinish = GetLastDockerBuildNumber(DockerBuildJobName)
        
while(true)
{
  if (IsAllDockerBuildJobsFinished(buildsNumberStart, buildNumberFinish, DockerBuildJobName))
  {
    break;
  }
        
  sleep(5)
}
        
for (build in GetFinishedJobs(buildsNumberStart, buildNumberFinish, DockerBuildJobName))
{
  def listener = build.getListener()
  build
    .getEnvironment(listener)
    .each
    {
      // HERE IS PROBLEM, I saw just environment variables that
      // set on start and didn`t see that I added in pipeline 
      println it
    }
 }
}

@NonCPS
def GetFinishedJobs(buildNumbersStart, buildNumberFinish, String dockerBuildJobName)
{
  return jenkins.model.Jenkins
    .instance
    .getItemByFullName(dockerBuildJobName)
    .builds
    .findAll { it.number > buildNumbersStart && it.number <= buildNumberFinish}
}
```

Comment: For me important to get job object because in next part of code I get some environment variable from job that have some result of work. Code example -
`job.buildVariables.ImageTag`

Comment: What are you going to do with the results? Are the number of Jobs static?

Comment: @ycr I get docker image tag as result of child jobs. Number of jobs not static. Also I update my question and add more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/40148397/14392639
for my case its looks like:

```
def jobs = [:]
some_source.each
{
  item -> jobs[some_source.Name] = build job: job_name,  parameters:
  [
    string(name: 'Param1', value: Value1),
    string(name: 'Param2', value: Value2),
    string(name: 'Param3', value: Value3),
  ]
}
  
parallel jobs
```